# How to create Tamil Language Based Web Application in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I planed to create Departmental Store Laravel Web Application in Tamil Language Not Using English. How to do it?

Comment: Read Here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization

Comment: Let me know do you need any more helps @Karthik??

Comment: Sorry for late Replaying @HirenGohel Thanks for your Support

Comment: Np brother! Let me know if you want any more helps from me? Please accept my answer as well also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create web apps using laravel's Localization.
For that, you need to create language strings. Language strings are stored in files within the `resources/lang` directory.

You need to create locale:

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
   App::setLocale($locale);

   //
});
```

Then create file within that directory and save it `messages.php` name like this:

```
<?php

   return [
      'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
   ];
?>
```

Then you need to use this as in any blade file like:

```
@lang('messages.welcome')
```

Also, please read the laravel docs from here:
[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#introduction)

Answer (score -1):

In your encoding defined at DB and front end use - UTF-8 encoding which supports most of the international languages