# Laravel 5.5 multi language application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I followed [this article](https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale) on how to make your site multi language.
But I don't understand why I always get an error when I surf to `hoemstead.app/lang/en` for example.

The error:

> Sorry, the page that you're looking for does not exist

My LanguageController

```
use Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLang($lang)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages'))) {
            Session::put('applocale', $lang);
        }
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', ['as'=>'lang.switch', 'uses'=>'LanguageController@switchLang']);
```

My Language Middleware

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class Language
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('applocale') AND array_key_exists(Session::get('applocale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('applocale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I've also added this middleware to my Kernel.php file

My Languages.php file in the config folder

```
return [
    'en' => 'English',
    'nl' => 'Nederlands',
    'fr' => 'Français',
];
```

Comment: your code will just set selected language in `session`, you need to add keywords entries for all languages & get language translation based on keyword using `__` function like this `{{ __('messages.welcome') }}` [documantation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization#retrieving-translation-strings)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381422/how-to-create-tamil-language-based-web-application-in-larave-5-4/44381551#44381551

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik I did this in my blade views

Comment: @HirenGohel I saw that in the laravel documentation but I have no idea where to put the `App::setLocale($locale);` for it to be active over my whole application.

Comment: @Chris You can check this, it's give you ideas! https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website

Comment: @HirenGohel Thanks for the link but it seems outdated, I am using Laravel 5.5 and my file structure looks different and my RouteServiceProvider.php also is different

Comment: @Chris, please follow the whole documentation, it will guide you how to setup keywords and languages entries, also please check if `session` is setting selected language or not.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik I just did `App::setLocale($locale);` in my controller function it seems to be working only on 1 page

Comment: You need to create `localization` middleware and use that middleware in all those routes where you want to use it!

Comment: Can you setup this [package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) and see.

Comment: @HirenGohel It's the first time I use Laravel I have no idea what a middleware is and how to use it

Comment: Then there is a lot of things you need to first learn it out! :)

Comment: @HirenGohel Unfortunately there is no time :/ I need to fix this multi lang in this Laravel project. It will be the only time ever I work in a Laravel project so there is no need to actually learn everything I just want it to work. Can't believe it is actually so hard even tho I always hear Laravel makes things simple XD